# Website Conversion Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, t-test

I have two separate versions of a website that I am currently testing. We ran both the websites over a seven day period and they returned the following metrics:

Website A - Number of Visitors: 2400
Website A - Overall Conversions: 1392
Website A - Conversion Rate: 9%

Website B - Number of Visitors: 1172
Website B - Overall Conversions: 1090
Website A - Conversion Rate: 12%

I am trying to see which Conversion Rate is better based on the given information. Additionally, looking to find out what the best type of statistical test to use in this situation.

Comment: The math doesn't work right in your examples.  1392/2400 is not 9%. And you have a typo in the 2nd para. And "better" is easy - whichever is higher is better. o you want a significance test?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a simple test you ***could*** do to indicate the significance of the conversion rate.  I'm unclear how the numbers 2400, 1392 and 9% fit together, so I'll use the 9% and the 1392 to extrapolate an example.

You could, for example, do a chi-square test on the following table:

```
Method  Converted  Didn'tConvert
A       1392       14075          [Total = 15467,  9%]
B       1090        7993          [Total =  9083, 12%]
```

Because the counts are high, the test will probably return a very significant result.

But the result may have been highly significant if the difference were 9% and 10% or 9% and 9.5%.  So, this kind of statistical best may not be very useful for you.

Instead, you will probably need to determine what measurements and what size of those measurements would be meaningful.  For example, Method B has a higher percent of conversions, but a lower absolute count of conversions.  Which metric is the one of interest for you?  Let's say it's the percentage.  How large of a percentage makes a difference to you?  Are there costs associated with implementing Method B?  Is it worth those costs to get an extra 3% conversion?  What if it were 2% or 1%?  And how stable are your results.  If you get a million visitors per year, should you rely on a couple of batches of 10,000 visits?  Would it be better to run these Methods for a while and see if there are changes maybe seasonally?

If the example I gave above is the kind of thing that makes sense, you might also look at the effect size statistic called *phi*.  But keep in the mind that a small *phi* may seem small, but a small difference could translate to a large difference in money if the sample size is large.

Comment: Should I be concerned at all with the varying amount of visitors that I had to my site? I feel like that variable should be addressed somehow when assessing the conversion percentage.

Comment: I don't know.  Is the difference in visitors likely to be from the difference in Method? Or is there something else that explains it?

Comment: Difference in method.

Comment: Then that total visitors or total conversions is really what you are interested in, not the percent conversions.

Comment: So within my test I am only interested in just conversions. Would my "n" just end up being the amount of days that my websites ran for?

Comment: Yes,, one approach would be to look at the number of conversions for each day for each method. An appropriate statistical test would be a paired sample Wilcoxon signed rank test. There are other options. Plotting the data across the seven days will give you a sense of if the differences were consistent across days.